# Average column value based on other column value vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I have following data ( just few are shown)

[image: ![enter image description here]

I need to get the average value for similar groups in column 3. There are many names in column 1( not shown all) and these names are different time to time, therefore I cant specify name  in the command line as it is not convenient. Can you please help me to put a vba code to solve this problem. Thanks.

```
Column 1  Column 2       
123A        1245
123A        3400
123A        1200
124A        1201
124A        1001
111B        900
123B        800
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to require VBA -- just a simple ratio of  `SUMIF()` and `COUNTIF()`

Comment: Or a simple AVERAGEIF(): `=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A1,B:B)` and copy down.  It will fill the average of all like names in column A.

Comment: @ScottCraner I forgot about `AverageIf()`, which is of course even shorter.

Comment: What would be the desired output.  Show the actual return you would expect to get in the picture you provided.

Comment: @Scott, I have updated with the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a list to the side:

```
Sub dupremoveavg()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet13") ' Change to your sheet

With ws
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    With .Range("A1:B" & lastrow)
        .Offset(, 4).Value = .Value
    End With
    With .Range("B2:B" & lastrow)
        .Offset(, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(C1,RC1,C[-4])"
        .Offset(, 4).Value = .Offset(, 4).Value
    End With

    .Range("E1:F" & lastrow).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes

End With

End Sub
```

[image]

---

Or for non vba you can use AVERAGEIF()

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B)
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

As per your edits.

Use this formula in C2 and copy down.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:$A$20000,MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:$A$20000<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:$B$20000,MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:$A$20000<>A2,)),0))),"")
```

[image]

This formula will reference a dynamic range, in that it will alwyas grow or shrink to accommodate the changing number of rows.

```
=IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0))),"")
```

Comment: Thank You very much. this is not directly addressing my problem. Please see the attached excel sheet. also please note that this data set goes to about 100 rows and will have different IDs next day. I can do it manually but if i can run a code would save time. My idea is first look the first ID value, and store the second row value, go to the next row to check the ID is same if same get the second row value, like wise calculate the average until find the next different ID. Hope you got my point. thanks

Comment: Please show in your **original post** the desired output exactly as you see it.

Comment: @ scott Thank you. it works, it addressed my requirements later i will try code. thank you.