# Add a reference cell formula in to a code

Tags: vba, excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48OqU.jpg)

[image]

[This is what would be the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCqOg.jpg)

[image]

I have this formula in cell "C1" To average the values in column2 with respected to column1 values.It gives what I need to do. But I want to get this work into a vba code.

Can anyone help to put this into a code. Is it possible when we have reference cells in the formula?? or do we need to go to more complex code??

```
=IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0))),"")
```

Comment: Record it with the macro recorder?

Comment: The macro recorder will only help if you want to *enter the formula* by using VBA. I think, he wants to *perform the calculation* in VBA; that's not possible with the macro recorder. A possible solution which is analogous to the formula approach would be to use the `WorksheetFunction` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Average column value based on other column value vba code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921899/average-column-value-based-on-other-column-value-vba-code)

Comment: @vacip It's not just a duplicate, it's the same person with the same question. Apparently not happy with the Answer, so trying again...

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do **C1**'s calculation is *VBA*:

```
Sub DoingC1Job()
    Dim s As String, s2 as string
    s = "=IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0))),??)"
    s = Replace(s, "??", Chr(34) & Chr(34))
    s2 = Evaluate(s)
    MsgBox s2
End Sub
```

The **??** is just an easy way to get the double-quotes into the string.

As improved by Leviathan:

```
Sub DoingC1Job()
    Dim s As String, v As Variant
    s = "=IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0))),"""")"
    v = Evaluate(s)
    MsgBox v
End Sub
```

Comment: S Hi Thanks, it gives the answer for my first set, can we copy "S" down to other cells and get the answers in the Column C at respective cells.?? please see the picture?

Comment: `TEXT(,)` replaces `""` in a string formula nicely as well.

Comment: Yes, but we would modify **s** in a loop to change the **1** and **2** cell references

Comment: @ Gary's Thank you, I will go from that.

Comment: "*The ?? is just an easy way to get the double-quotes into the string.*" -- Why not just use `s = "=IF(A2<>A1, ... <>A2,)),0))),"""")"`, why the `Replace()`?

Comment: @Leviathan  My personal mental problem...........I have trouble keeping track of the number of double quotes

Comment: @Gary's Student: Mhmm... well, I don't think it is a good idea to show this kind of workaround in an answer. Since it will only work if no other question marks are present in the string, this can easily introduce new errors. If you get confused by doubling all quotes (you could use the search&replace feature of your favourite text editor to automate this), instead of replacing them by question marks, directly replace them by `" & Chr(34) & "`. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9024764/6216216 for handling double quotes in strings.

Comment: @Leviathan  I am forced to agree with you and I will edit my answer.........thank you for your help.........

Comment: Thanks, now it's +1. :)