# vba Code to average excel data

Tags: vba, excel

I have three columns "SAMPLE ID" Results , Average

Eg:

```
SAMPLE ID 
1201
1201
1201
1201
1300
1300
1300
1300
1400
Results 
400
490
340
400
400
490
233
400
290
```

I used the following formula to get the average  in column 3. I want to this to be done in vba. My data set is long (only few are shown)

1. Can  I fill this formula down to other cell using vba (even without typing it in the first cell)

2.can we define this as a string and copy it down??? all the helps are appriciated. or any other way of coding to this Thanks

```
= IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0))),"")
```

Comment: This exact question was [asked and has been answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948413/add-a-reference-cell-formula-in-to-a-code) within the last 12 hours.

Comment: It is not exact Q, don't judge with appearance, read the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Sub main()
With Worksheets("averages") '<== change it as per your actual worksheet name
    Range("C1:C" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).formula = "= IF(A2<>A1,AVERAGEIF(A2:INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0)),A2,B2:INDEX($B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1),MATCH(TRUE,(INDEX($A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)<>A2,)),0))),"""")"
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Vasily, The code is perfect. Thank you, can we modify it not to display the formula in the respective cells in excel? I tried this but not doing the work Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rng As Range
   For Each rng In Target.Cells
      If rng.HasFormula Then
         ActiveSheet.Protect
         Exit Sub
      Else
         ActiveSheet.Unprotect
      End If
   Next rng
End Sub